# Vue how to add element to v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my `vue`-app I want to add an element inside a `v-for`-loop. So I tried to do this:

```
<li v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index"
  :class="slideIndex === index ? 'active' : ''"
  @click="slideIndex = index"
>
 {{ slide.nodeName }}
</li>
<li class="cursor-pointer item" v-if="slides.length === 5">foobar</li>
```

but this doesn't keep the "new" item inside the index e.g. I want the element to be inside the loop.

How can I solve that?

Comment: I don´t understand your question. Do you want the second `<li>` to be included in the loop of your first `<li>`?

Comment: @StevenSiebert yes, exactly :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that if slides.length === 5, then add your second `<li>` tag after each `<li>` tag?
If yes, please take a look at the following code

```html
<template v-for="(slide, index) in slides">
  <li
    :key="slide.nodeName"
    :class="slideIndex === index ? 'active' : ''"
    @click="slideIndex = index"
  >
    {{ slide.nodeName }}
  </li>
  <li
    :key="`${slide.nodeName}_${index}`"
    class="cursor-pointer item"
    v-if="slides.length === 5"
  >
    foobar
  </li>
</template>
```

Please pay attention to the key value binding of the `<li>` tag at the same level

Answer (score -1):

```
<el-row v-for="item in queryFolderList" :key="item.id">
  <el-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="24" :lg="24" :xl="24">
    <el-button-group>
      <el-button type="primary" size="mini" @click="goToDetil(item.id)"
        >{{ item.id }}</el-button
      >
      <el-button type="warning" size="mini" @click="submit(item.id)"
        >{{ item.name}}</el-button
      >
    </el-button-group>
  </el-col>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To include elements to the loop of other elements in `vue.js`, you need to include them into their tag. In your case you need to be aware of, that nesting `<li>` into `<li>` can cause problems. Try this:

```
<li v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index"
  :class="slideIndex === index ? 'active' : ''"
  @click="slideIndex = index"
>
 {{ slide.nodeName }}
  <ul v-if="slides.length === 5">
    <li class="cursor-pointer item">foobar</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

As the loop is on your first `<li>` element, everything between `<li>` and `</li>` of that element will be included into the loop. I added an `<ul>` around your second `<li>` for the nested list.

---

**EDIT: Render second `<li>` if 5 slides in `slides`**

So now that I think to know what you trying to achieve, let´s try to solve it. The second `<li>` has to be rendered after 5 loops done/if there are 5 slides in `slides`.

First you need to note, that `v-if="slides.length === 5"` only matches, if there are exactly 5 slides. So if you now provide something with a `slides.length` bigger than 5 or smaller, your `<li>` with `foobar` don´t show. Change it to `v-if="slides.length > 5"` instead. If `<li>` with `foobar` only should be shown if the `length` IS 5, then your code is working as it should.

But if you try to add `<li>` with `foobar` AFTER 5 items or even every 5 items, you could use this little trick:

```
<ul>
   <span v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index">
      <li :class="slideIndex === index ? 'active' : ''"
         @click="slideIndex = index"
      >
         {{ slide.nodeName }}
      </li>
      <li class="cursor-pointer item" v-if="(index + 1)%5 === 0">foobar</li>
   </span>
</ul>
```

You shouldn´t include `<span>` in `<ul>`, but it should work. Now the loop runs for both `<li>` elements, but `<li>` with `foobar` only renders after each 5th element, due to `v-if="(index + 1)%5 === 0"`.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: but this adds a `<ul>` after each item if the `slides.length` is equal to 5...

Comment: @ST80 Yes, that would be the case. I edited the answer and moved the condition to the `<ul>` itself.

Comment: the second `<li>` should be included after all the other `<li>`-elements has been rendered...

Comment: @ST80 Edited my answer. Take a look.